# Fragment list, infinite loading spinner

Tags: android, android-fragments

i want to remove a "infinite loading spinner" from my screen. I post a default fragment list code generated from android studio:

```
public class DummyContent {

/**
 * An array of sample (dummy) items.
 */
public static final List<DummyItem> ITEMS = new ArrayList<DummyItem>();

/**
 * A map of sample (dummy) items, by ID.
 */
public static final Map<String, DummyItem> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<String, DummyItem>();

private static final int COUNT = 25;

static {
    // Add some sample items.
    for (int i = 1; i <= COUNT; i++) {
        addItem(createDummyItem(i));
    }
}

private static void addItem(DummyItem item) {
    ITEMS.add(item);
    ITEM_MAP.put(item.id, item);
}

private static DummyItem createDummyItem(int position) {
    return new DummyItem(String.valueOf(position), "Item " + position, makeDetails(position));
}

private static String makeDetails(int position) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("Details about Item: ").append(position);
    for (int i = 0; i < position; i++) {
        builder.append("\nMore details information here.");
    }
    return builder.toString();
}

/**
 * A dummy item representing a piece of content.
 */
public static class DummyItem {
    public final String id;
    public final String content;
    public final String details;

    public DummyItem(String id, String content, String details) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
        this.details = details;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

}

My adapter:

```
public class MyProvaRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyProvaRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private final List<DummyItem> mValues;
private final OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public MyProvaRecyclerViewAdapter(List<DummyItem> items, OnListFragmentInteractionListener listener) {
    mValues = items;
    mListener = listener;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_prova, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
    holder.mIdView.setText(mValues.get(position).id);
    holder.mContentView.setText(mValues.get(position).content);

    holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (null != mListener) {
                // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
                // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
                mListener.onListFragmentInteraction(holder.mItem);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mValues.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public final View mView;
    public final TextView mIdView;
    public final TextView mContentView;
    public DummyItem mItem;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mView = view;
        mIdView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
        mContentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + " '" + mContentView.getText() + "'";
    }
}
```

}

```
public class ProvaFragment extends Fragment {

// TODO: Customize parameter argument names
private static final String ARG_COLUMN_COUNT = "column-count";
// TODO: Customize parameters
private int mColumnCount = 1;
private OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */
public ProvaFragment() {
}

// TODO: Customize parameter initialization
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static ProvaFragment newInstance(int columnCount) {
    ProvaFragment fragment = new ProvaFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT, columnCount);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mColumnCount = getArguments().getInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_prova_list, container, false);

    // Set the adapter
    if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
        Context context = view.getContext();
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
        if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        } else {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
        }
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyProvaRecyclerViewAdapter(DummyContent.ITEMS, mListener));
    }
    return view;
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnListFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnListFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnListFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p/>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnListFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onListFragmentInteraction(DummyItem item);
}
```

}

I can't understand why when i start it with:

```
ProvaFragment pf = new ProvaFragment();
FragmentTransaction lfrg = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment, pf);
    lfrg.commitNow();
```

generate a default list with an infinite loading spinner in center of fragment,but it never declared, how can i remove that?

My XML code for fragment prova:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />
```

and for fragment_prova list:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/list"
android:name="com.example.simi.myapplication.ProvaFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
tools:context="com.example.simi.myapplication.ProvaFragment"
tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_prova" />
```

Comment: post your xml code

Comment: i have post it.

Comment: there must be something you are missing ... post your full activity code and xml where you are calling fragment

Comment: that is all code, in my onCreate method i declare only 3 previous rows, provafragment and fragment transition